# How to fix toggleComplete for Todo React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you click on a list item in the to-do list, it should strikethrough, indicating you are finished with the task, however, when I click on the list item, nothing happens. Below is my toggleComplete function and where I want to call the function:

```
class TodoForm extends Component {
  state = {
    item: ''
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      item: this.state.item,
      complete: false
    });
    this.setState({
      item: ''
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          name="item"
          value={this.state.item}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add Todo</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  state = {
    item: {
      todo: "todo", 
      complete: false
    },
    items: [],
    complete: true
  };

  addTodo = todo => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: [todo, ...state.items]
    }));
  };

  toggleComplete = id => {.    //<---- toggleComplete function not working
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            complete: !todo.complete
          };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      })
    }));
  };

  render() {
    let items = this.state.items;
    return (
        <div>
          <TodoForm onSubmit={this.addTodo} />
          {items.map(todo => (
            <ul
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center"
              }}
              key={todo.id}
              toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)}
              todo={todo}
            >
              <li
                style={{
                  textDecoration: todo.complete ?
                    "line-through" : ""
                }}
                onClick={this.toggleComplete}> //<--- where I am trying to call the function
                {todo.item}
              </li>
            </ul>
          ))}
          <div>
            {this.state.items.filter(todo => !todo.complete).length} remaining out of {this.state.items.length}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, when you click on the item and the text strikes through, the tasks left to do also decrements. I would appreciate help with this problem

Comment: li  onClick should be `onClick={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)}` and remove `toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)}` and `todo={todo}` props  from ul, they are not valid props for ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because you are passing two event handlers.

1. On `Li` so it pass id as `event`
2. On `ul` since `toggleComplete` is not browser property so its not invoking because of that. If its `onClick` it will invoke because of bubbling.

Fix for this is:

1. remove `toggleComplete` from `ul`
2. Pass `onClick={() => this.toggleComplete(todo.id)}` in `li`

Here is complete code and demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/great-blackburn-ti0d1?file=/src/App.js:1762-1821